# Eslint somehow got messed up, Shopware build fails

Tags: npm, eslint, shopware, shopware6

I have a big problem with the Node.js module `eslint` within Shopware 6. Out of nowhere I get an error message about a conflicting dependency while building Showpware's storefront and administration:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0
npm ERR! Found: eslint@7.10.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"7.10.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!     @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"5.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   14 more (@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils, eslint-utils, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^13.2.0" from @shopware-ag/eslint-config-base@1.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@shopware-ag/eslint-config-base
npm ERR!     @shopware-ag/eslint-config-base@"1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@5.16.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-airbnb-base@"13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^13.2.0" from @shopware-ag/eslint-config-base@1.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@shopware-ag/eslint-config-base
npm ERR!       @shopware-ag/eslint-config-base@"1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Neither did I manually modify any parts of the Shopware core nor did I install any updates. This error message shows up when I run `build.sh`. At some point it executes `build-js.sh` which crashes immediately. This also happened to other Shopware installations we maintain. I also tried to reinstall a broken installation from scratch but after some time it shows the same error message when I start the building process.

All affected installations run with Shopware 6.4.x.x.
Node.js is 16.15.1 LTS, npm is 8.11.0

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the information about your node js version.

Comment: OK, version details added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember that this problem existed a while ago. The problem is that Node 16.15.1 bumped the NPM version from 8.5.5 to 8.11.0. This causes the peer dependency problem. However, we fixed this issue in mid-May. So with trunk and the latest 6.4 release, the problem should vanish. If that's not the case, try to fix this by changing npm to a version <8.11.0.

Comment: It works! I downgraded to Node 16.15.0 which contains npm 8.5.5!
Thank you so much! 